# Why pick 262144 Hz oscillator frequency?

Tags: oscillator, clock, crystal, rtc

Some Bulova watches (for example the Precisionist collection) use 262144 Hz crystal oscillators instead of the usual 32768 Hz. What are the true advantages of this higher frequency, if they even exist?

The usual quartz clock frequency is 32768 Hz because that's the lowest power of two above 20 kHz. This means the usual frequency is above human hearing range, but still allows ticking at one second intervals by simply dividing with 2^15.

Bulova claims their ~262 kHz watches are an order of magnitude more precise (~10 seconds per year vs the ~15 seconds per month of standard quartz watches). Do higher frequencies really help with precision or is it just marketing?

Their ~262 kHz watches also tick eight times per second. Many people enjoy this smoother motion, and it feels a bit more like a mechanical watch. But couldn't they achieve exactly the same effect by just dividing the usual ~32 kHz by 2^12? It seems like they chose to maintain the 2^15 divisor, for some reason.

Comment: 32768 * 8 = 262144... They are using a crystal 8 times the frequency to get precision that is about 1.5 times the "standard quartz".

Comment: Actually, I've seen numerous smooth running quartz wall clocks, so you are at least correct on that.

Comment: The **drawback** of higher frequency is a higher power consumption.

Comment: since when is 32768Hz within the range of human hearing?

Comment: @Ron I know about *8, which is what the last paragraph of the question is about. Can you elaborate on the 1.5 times the precision? Where does the number come from and what makes higher frequencies more precise?

Comment: @DK It's not. That is exactly why it's commonly used. I'll edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: well sounds like marketing to me. for the same ppm a higher and lower frequemcy should be just as accurate if you dont care about reading time to a resolution of less than a second.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was thinking the same. The accuracy is given in ppm and is **independent** of frequency.

Comment: Regarding resolution (=/= accuracy): The thing has a 1/1000 second chrono hand, but still a 32768 Hz would do fine enough to give an accurate 1 ms reading. Moreover: 1 ms reading for a human with a reaction time of 250 ms LOL!

Comment: From the manual ```ABOUT THE POWER CELL
Your new Quartz Watch has a fresh power cell designed to provide maximum reliability for approximately a year under normal use.``` Quite useful if the deviation is only x seconds per year, when you have to replace the battery and therefore have to calibrate the time again each year

Comment: BTW precision =/= accuracy [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) If you would replace the 32768 Hz crystal by a 20000 Hz crystal in a watch, you will still have a good precision, but a bad accuracy.

Comment: Watch companies keep it as a very deep trade secret the knowledge they gain on operating crystals to drive their watch systems. I've tried, hard, to get at that information. It's more work than I was able to afford, to get much at all. (I did get a few things.) Anyway, the first thing that comes to mind is that it allowed them to use a smaller tuning fork, which required less space in the watch, and that they'd researched how to make it operate on sufficiently low enough power to compete close enough with 32kHz tuning fork crystals that their marketing would not be harmed.

Comment: I worked for Seiko on their message-watch, some many years ago. While working as a contractor for them, I was amazed that they could handle the message watch features (requiring very power-hungry RF reception), run a Western Digital custom ASIC of the 65C02 processor, and keep time and run for two years on a button battery. You can well imagine that I wanted very very much to learn from what I was working on. But their was no possible way I could get at the info. It was very strongly compartmentalized. Frustrated, not being allowed to learn something interesting. But there it was.

Comment: *if* the thermal compensation (a very big if) is of a closed loop type, then a higher frequency can result in a faster compensation loop.

Comment: I can't find any 262144 Hz oscillators on DigiKey or anywhere else. Do they not exist in the public domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already commented, the accuracy doesn't depend on frequency.
It does significantly depend on temperature.

> What Is ‘High Accuracy Quartz’?
>   Most watches rocking a quartz movement are guaranteed accurate to around **15 seconds a month** or so. This is still much better than even the best mechanical watches, but there’s a breed of quartz watches out there that can do even better: the High Accuracy Quartz (HAQ). HAQ’s **still operate under the same principals as standard quartz movements**, but they take into account the one major threat to quartz accuracy: changes in temperature. HAQ’s are, thus, **thermo-compensated** and can detect these changes and adjust themselves accordingly, which typically results in a guaranteed accuracy rate of around **10 seconds per year**.

Source: https://gearpatrol.com/2018/08/20/your-complete-guide-to-quartz-watches/

It's quite likely they used thermo-compensation, which has nothing to do with frequency.

A drawback of a higher frequency is a higher power consumption.
Their manual suggests the battery should be replaced each year which sounds frequent to me (I havent replaced the battery of my cheap watch the last 3 years).

Comment: Wow it is definitely a power hog. Batteries should usually last about five years, give or take. Casio has a bunch of 10-year-battery models, many of which are also cheap. Though ticking 8 times per second is probably a more significant contributor to low battery life than the frequency.